# Creating a grid of rectangles that increase in alpha values up to 255 using for loops

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I created a grid of rectangles that increase in opacity as you go down and right.  I've divided the 256 alpha values evenly into 4 columns (64 rectangles per column).

I'm trying to cut the code down by using `for` loops for each column.

I've managed to created the column of rectangles, but the fill() `for` I've setup isn't applying the opacity how I need it to.

Here's what I'm running for column 1:

```
  for (var a = 0; a < 256; a++) {
    fill(155,0,0,a);
  }

  var y = 0;
  for (var x = 0; y <= 1890; x += 210) {
    for (var y = 0; y <= 1890; y += 30) {
      rect(x,y,200,20)
    }
  }
```

I've tried combining the fill() and rect() loops, but I get the same issue where the color scale sticks to (155,0,0,255) rather than starting at 0 and going up to 63 (for this column alone).

I'm capped at 4 `fill` & 4 `rect` lines in total (e.g. 1 fill-rect-combo per column).

For the complete code and visual representation of the grid, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvdJWB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `for` loop runs, and finishes, before the nested `for` loop even starts. You can think about your program as equivalent to this:

```
  fill(155,0,0,0);
  fill(155,0,0,1);
  fill(155,0,0,2);
  fill(155,0,0,3);
  //...
  fill(155,0,0,254);
  fill(155,0,0,255);


  var y = 0;
  for (var x = 0; y <= 1890; x += 210) {
    for (var y = 0; y <= 1890; y += 30) {
      rect(x,y,200,20)
    }
  }
```

This makes it obvious that your first `for` loop isn't really doing much, and only the last call to `fill()` really matters.

If you want each cell, or each row or column, to be a different color, then you're going to have to call `fill()` inside the nested `for` loop somewhere.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, so I tried moving the `fill()` loop to engulf the `rect()` loops, and vice versa, but remains the same.  I'm having trouble determining where in the loops the `fill` should go.

I know the `fill()` should come before the `rect()` but past that, I'm a bit confused. For example, this is what I'm drawn to, but isn't working: http://i.imgur.com/fveqCyM.png

Comment: You only need your double-nested `for` loop, not a triple-nested `for` loop. Start with something simpler: can you make every cell a different color? Then build on that. Graph paper is your best friend. Draw out a bunch of examples. What are the values of `x` and `y`, and what value do you want `a` to have for each combination? Try to find a pattern.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but it clicked for me. with your advice.  I didn't do anything with a different color, but i changed the way the alpha value was calculated without creating an `a` variable.  The thing is, it worked with only 1 `for` loop.... don't know how I randomly got that to work.  I was originally struggling because I had forgotten that I was splitting them up into 4 columns, and so I was trying to create 1 nested `for` loop to make all columns, so there was my 1st `for` loop gone.  Anyway, thank you. This is the result for column 1 http://i.imgur.com/90zsuqx.png

Comment: @noobiecderssss Nice. Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Looking for that pattern/relationship between the alpha and x/y coordinates really helped out! (last comment was too long).

Comment: @noobiecderssss Yeah, that's how I like to approach [for loops](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/for-loops): looking for a pattern, looking at the loop variable, and trying to find the relationship between them. Graph paper helps me with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150431/discussion-between-noobiecderssss-and-kevin-workman).